# How can I plan my diet from scratch?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, workout-routines, food

I want to plan a new lifestyle. My goal is to lose some weight and get healthier. I think this is the time for me to make some self-progress.
Is there anything I should keep in mind or know before I start?
Regarding metabolism and body type, I'm  an endomorph. Please suggest the dos and don'ts for me.

I know that you (maybe some are) are not nutritionists or dieticians, but  any word of advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help making a diet / meal plan for \[Exercise Regime\]. What do I do?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29860/i-need-help-making-a-diet-meal-plan-for-exercise-regime-what-do-i-do)

Comment: FYI somatypes (endomorph/ectomorph/ectoplasm/etc.) are disproven. They don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is eat clean and eat regularly. If you are not working out, make sure you don't eat more than what you actually require. The idea is to keep the complete nutrition in mind. Make sure the sources you pick, provide you with all the necessary nutrients for your body to get nourished and stay in proper condition.  I don't know what your prior eating habits were like, but if you were into junk, and unhealthy food, then cut those as much as possible. I know it's just hard, but to lead a healthy lifestyle, you need to give up certain stuffs. If you can't resist the craving, keep it down to 1 day a week, but eat those in limit.  Drink plenty of water and rest well. Maintain good hygiene which is very important. Above all, have a positive mindset and just focus on the goal. Once you attain it, maintain it. Don't spiral down back to where you started. Wish you the best.